# Why use `IdentifierName` symbol recursively in the productions for the `IdentifierName`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I'm looking at the following productions of the `IdentifierName` symbol in the lexical [EcmaScript grammar](http://IdentifierName):

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart
```

I'm wondering why the grammar uses `IdentifierName` in the second row of productions?

I was thinking first that `IdentifierName` can be expanded into `IdentifierStart` and hence for the `IdentifierName` we can get the following:

```
IdentifierName -> IdentifierStart IdentifierPart
```

But isn't that case then can be put like this?

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierStart IdentifierPart

    ^^^^
    here `IdentifierStart` instead of `IdentifierName`
```

How using this grammar I can build a parse tree for the variable name `git`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `IdentifierStart` and `IdentifierPart` only match a single character each. So if the rule were `IdentifierName -> IdentifierStart IdentifierPart`, it would only match identifiers with a length of exactly 2 and your second suggestion would match identifiers of length 1 or 2.

The recursion is how the rule can match identifiers of arbitrary length.

---

Here's how you'd derive "git":

```
                 IdentifierName
                /              \
        IdentifierName IdentifierPart
       /              \         |
IdentifierName IdentifierPart  't'
       |                |
IdentiiferStart        'i'
       |
      'g'
```

Comment: thanks, so the first production `IdentifierName -> IdentifierStart` will only match a name of one character, correct?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Correct.

Comment: thanks, using your answer I'm now trying to create a parse tree for the `git` variable name but I'm stuck. Can you please take a look at the updated question? Or I can create a separate question